# Dynamic select in a nested form with cocoon

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, nested-forms

I was developing a form and I got to the point where I can not go forward.

I have a nested form, with 4 levels,

Project -> Level_one -> Level_two -> Level_three.

And wanted to do a dropdown in some categories already pre-registered in another object that is also nested, but this time with three levels.

Category -> Division_one -> Division_two.

How do I get Level_one to grab Category attributes, and then Level_two then grab the Division_one attributes depending on the Category chosen?

I found an example, but it is in the same form and with the same object.

https://github.com/vtamara/cocoon-ajax-project-objective-result-indicator

I tried to adapt, but it did not work.

**Update**

Here I am picking up the category to level_one:

```
<%= f.collection_select :title, Category.order(:name), :name, :name %>
```

Here I am picking up division_one to level_two:

```
<%= f.grouped_collection_select :title, Category.order(:name), :division_one, :name, :id, :name %>
```

And now I'm trying to get the division_three for level_three, but it's still not working, any ideas?

```
<%= f.select :name, Category.division_ones.collect(&:division_two), :division_two,  :id, :name %>
```

Still bringing everything, I do not know how to make it look dynamic, bring it according to the selection of the previous one, with the javascript, does anyone have some tutorial to recommend?

Comment: I think the problem you're running into is that Cocoon renders the children ahead of time into a template, and then just copies that template. Because you're getting into some pretty complex UI, I would recommend possibly looking into something Like React or another JavaScript library that could give you the power you're looking for.

Comment: in javascript have you seen anything like this?